# Can't start CLRprofiler on WSL on Windows 11, but it works on Windows 10

Tags: .net, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clr-profiling-api, clrprofiler

I have been using CLRProfiler on Linux (using WSL) on my Windows 10 machine.

I got new machine with Windows 11, and I am trying to do same, meaning that I am using WSL (Ubuntu) and the same code for running the CLRProfiler, but it's not starting.

I've checked all the environment variables and they look the same on both computers.

The only difference seems to be the operating system (Win11/Win10).

How can I diagnose the problem with CLRProfiler on Windows 11?

Comment: Same here. Have you found a Solution?

Comment: @cmadh - yes, 
1. copy the dll that you inject to  Ubuntu\usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu 2. also check if the dependency dll are embedded compile - if not so copy them also